# dbms_output.put_line write out each value from function

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got a function that takes three number arguments and returns a value calculated from those three numbers. Now in another stored procedure I call try to write out each value like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_POOL 
IS

BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test'||' '||POOL_PKG.F_REKTANGULÄR(6,4,2);
```

But I want to the output to be example:

```
test is 6 meter and 4 meter and 2 meter!
```

How can I add text after each value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Package POOL_PKG 
IS

FUNCTION F_REKTANGULÄR(meter_in NUMBER,height_in NUMBER,bottom_in NUMBER,Show_dims_in IN NUMBER := 0) RETURN NUMBER;

END POOL_PKG;

Package Body POOL_PKG is

FUNCTION F_REKTANGULÄR(meter_in NUMBER,height_in NUMBER,bottom_in NUMBER, Show_dims_in IN NUMBER := 0) RETURN NUMBER
v_result NUMBER(10);
v_unit VARCHAR2(10) := 'meter';
IS

--assert that all inputs are greater than 0
--and less than a reasonable amount

v_result := meter_in * height_in * bottom_in;
IF show_dims_in = 1 
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT(meter_in ||' '||v_unit||', '||height_in||' '||v_unit||', '||bottom_in);
END IF;
RETURN v_result;
END F_REKTANGULÄR;

END POOL_PKG;
```

and could be used this way
DECLARE
v_result NUMBER(9);
BEGIN
v_result := POOL_PKG.F_REKTANGULÄR(6 ,4 ,2,1);
END;

Or, given your comments this would work to:

```
Declare
a NUMBER(9);
b NUMBER(9);
c NUMBER(9);
v_unit VARCHAR2(10) := 'meter';
v_result NUMBER(9);
BEGIN
a := 6;
b := 4;
c := 2;

    DBMS_OUTPUT(a||' '||v_unit||', '||b||' '||v_unit||', '||c||' '||v_unit);
    v_result := POOL_PKG.F_REKTANGULÄR(a ,b ,c);
END;
```

Comment: Sorry was in a bit hurry :-) ok i Will try .  i want the output to be like this : 6 meter, 4 meter and 2 meter.

Comment: Cant you change in dbms_output?

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_POOL 
IS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(POOL_PKG.F_REKTANGULÄR(6,4,1.5));

is it impossible to pick out value 6 first and print out after, then 4, to get this:

spec: Lenght 6 meter, bottom 2 meter, height 1,5 meters.. ? Bec i have a stored procedure who call this function output..

Comment: Not without using more complicated methods to break down the results from the function.

Comment: Ok well when i write it out now i got this: 

speci:  Längd 6 meter, bredd  4 meter, höjd 1,5 meter
36
Volym:  36 meter
cost:  45 

i got 36 below, can i remove it?

Comment: IT WORKS! thank you :P i added the comment 

v_result NUMBER(9); BEGIN v_result := POOL_PKG.F_REKTANGULÄR(6 ,4 ,2,1);

in my procedure now it works good.. doesnt print out the 36 either perfect! ty :)